# Error when running chart-cairo Haskell program on Yosemite

Tags: macos, haskell, osx-yosemite

I've installed `chart` and `chart-cairo` from Hackage using Cabal on my Yosemite 10.10 Macbook Pro Retina (x86_64). I'm trying to compile and run the following sample program from Chart's official site:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart
import Data.Colour
import Data.Colour.Names
import Data.Default.Class
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend.Cairo
import Control.Lens

setLinesBlue :: PlotLines a b -> PlotLines a b
setLinesBlue = plot_lines_style  . line_color .~ opaque blue

chart = toRenderable layout
  where
    am :: Double -> Double
    am x = (sin (x*3.14159/45) + 1) / 2 * (sin (x*3.14159/5))

    sinusoid1 = plot_lines_values .~ [[ (x,(am x)) | x <- [0,(0.5)..400]]]
              $ plot_lines_style  . line_color .~ opaque blue
              $ plot_lines_title .~ "am"
              $ def

    sinusoid2 = plot_points_style .~ filledCircles 2 (opaque red)
              $ plot_points_values .~ [ (x,(am x)) | x <- [0,7..400]]
              $ plot_points_title .~ "am points"
              $ def

    layout = layout_title .~ "Amplitude Modulation"
           $ layout_plots .~ [toPlot sinusoid1,
                              toPlot sinusoid2]
           $ def

main = renderableToFile def "example1_big.png" chart
```

Doing so results on the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( haskell_chart.hs, haskell_chart.o )
Linking haskell_chart ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv, _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc1_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc_closure , _hs_iconv_open , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncodingzuloc1_closure , _hs_iconv_close , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_closure )
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_close)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_open)
  "_locale_charset", referenced from:
      _localeEncoding in libHSbase-4.7.0.2.a(PrelIOUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have the C library for `iconv` installed?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I do. I have the libiconv dynamic libs on the right directories. How can I double check it?

Comment: It's definitely some sort of installation or configuration issue, though difficult to work out what. I develop chart on yosemite, so it can work. This post describes how I set up my machine for haskell:  https://twdkz.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/haskell-on-yosemite-osx-10-10/